# Acknowledgement page + report

Tags: sectioning, numbering, starred-version

I'm writing a report and I want to place the Acknowledgement page without `\section` because it will number it 0.1

I tried to place it in another TeX document and use `\input` in the main document, but it did not work.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25798/how-can-i-add-abstract-and-acknowledgement-pages-into-the-table-of-contents

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the starred version of `\section`, `\section*`, to produced a non-numbered section as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\section*{Acknowledgement}% This section is not numbered
\chapter{Chapter name}
\section{Section name}% This section is numbered
\end{document}
```

If you want to add the starred section to the table of contents you will have to replace

```
\section*{Acknowledgement}
```

with

```
\section*{Acknowledgement}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}
```

Comment: There is of course also `\chapter*` which I personally use for the acknowledgement in my thesis, but what to use depends on the style.

Comment: What if like to refer to the starred section by using `\label{key}....\ref{key}`. in this case I will encounter a problem which is LaTeX will refer to the section in higher order or the previous one.

Comment: @AhmedNaji [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.